# Why does <a> tag with an image change element dimensions?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a header for my website and I want to place clickable social media logos that can redirect the user to that link. I am pretty new to frontend so from what I understand I have to place an anchor tag around the image element for it to be a clickable link. However placing the tag changes the dimensions of the element itself.

This works fine: [image is in the center with dims 25x25]

```
    <img 
      className='invert float-left' 
      src='/static/github.svg'
      height="25" 
      width="25"
      alt="github logo"
    />
```

However, this does not: [anchor element tag has dims 25x40 and thus offsets the image upwards]

```
<a href="<URL>">
  <img 
    className='invert' 
    src='/static/github.svg'
    height="25" 
    width="25"
    alt="github logo"
  />
</a>
```

Comment: By default, images have space beneath them, as they align with the baseline of any text that might sit beside them. You either need to set the image to `display: block` or perhaps set it to `display: inline-block` and then give it `vertical-align: bottom` to get rid of the extra vertical space.

Comment: @ralph.m Tried that, it lowers the image ever so slightly but still doesn't center it.

Comment: @vsharma14 Give the `<a>` the `inline-block` class and the `<img>` the `block` class.

Comment: @vsharma14 — we're only really guessing at the issue, as you haven't provided a live demo of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert `display: inline-flex;` on the `<a>` tag.

```html
<a href="https://github.com/" style="
    display: inline-flex;
">
  <img height="25" width="25" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/01/30/13/33/github-6980894_1280.png" alt="github">
</a>
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they contain a description of how the code solves the problem as well as pure code. You can edit your answer to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, change the image or link as needed.

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 4px">
   <a href="link">
    <img
      className="invert"
      src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple- 
      logotypes/512/github- 
      512.png"
      height="25"
      width="25"
      alt="github logo"
    /> </a
  >Github
</div>
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they contain a description of how the code solves the problem as well as pure code. You can edit your answer to provide more detail.